# How can I set max string field length constraint in Pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

So, I have pydantic model with a string field:

```
class MyPydanticModel(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]
```

And I want to set the max length for this field to 10. How can I do this?

Answer (score 34):

> ⚠️ This function is discouraged in favor of using Annotated with
> StringConstraints instead.
>
> This function will be deprecated in Pydantic 3.0.
>
> The reason is that constr returns a type, which doesn't play well with
> static analysis tools.

You can use [`constr`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/string_types/#constrained-types):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

class MyPydanticModel(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[constr(max_length=10)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to get back the `max_length` value? For example in a validator

Answer (score 13):

You can also use [`Field`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/), it has support for constraints too, for example:

If field is optional:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field 
from typing import Optional

class MyPydanticModel(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str] = Field(None, max_length=10)
```

If field is required:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field 
from typing import Optional

class MyPydanticModel(BaseModel):
    title: str = Field(..., max_length=10)
```

Comment: this works together with mypy, unlike `constr`

Answer (score 4):

This is what is recommended from [documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.StringConstraints) starting from pydantic v2.x:

```py
from typing import Annotated

from pydantic import BaseModel, StringConstraints


class MyPydanticModel(BaseModel):
    name: Annotated[str, StringConstraints(min_length=10)]
```